# Bound for the derivative of a $C^1$ curve

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, curves

I have a $C^1$ curve $\gamma:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbf{R}^n$, such that $\gamma(a,b)$ is contained in some compact set. How do I get a bound for $\gamma^{\prime}$?

My Attempt: for any $t\in(a,b),||\gamma^{\prime}(t)||=||D\gamma_t (1)||\leq ||D\gamma_t ||$. But still can't get rid of $t$. Is it always even bounded?

Comment: No, there is no reason why $\gamma'$ should be bounded.

Comment: Can you please mention about a counter example may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\gamma (t)=\sqrt t$ from $(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ shows that $\gamma'$ need not be bounded. If you want an example in which the domain is a closed interval consider $x \to x^{3/2} \sin (\frac 1 x)$ on $[0,1]$. (Assign the value $0$ at $x=0$).

Answer (score 2):

You can't prove it, since it is false. Take, for instance,$$\begin{array}{rccc}\gamma\colon&(-1,1)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^2\\&t&\mapsto&\left(t,\sqrt{1-t^2}\right).\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks, can you give a counter example where image is in $S^{n-1}$

Comment: In my example, the image is in $S^1$.

Comment: Yeah Sorry.... didn't notice it